# Reword the description of the blocklist page on the mod tools list

Tags: bug, status-review, moderator-tools, wording

[This recent post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392340/278659) clarifies that the `<site>.stackexchange.com/admin/blocklist` page includes not only fully blocklisted content but also content that generates warnings (such as, for example, automatic popups with links to further information on asking good questions within a particular tag).

Catija mentions that changes to this page would be a very low-priority item, given the low usage of this page and the relatively low impact of any changes. That completely makes sense, as changes like reorganising the whole page would take more time than the benefits would be worth. What I'm requesting here is (hopefully) a very simple change that would take a very little amount of time to implement.

The new `<site>.stackexchange.com/admin/links` contains a description of what's found behind each link, and the description of the blocklist page is currently as follows:

> Lists user inputs that the system will not accept on this site (e.g., in tags, comments, post titles, post bodies, display names, or universally). This list can only be modified by staff.

This doesn't seem quite accurate, following the clarifications made in the above-linked meta post. I suggest something like:

> Lists user inputs that are not accepted by the system, or will generate automatic warnings, on this site (e.g., in tags, comments, post titles, post bodies, display names, or universally). This list can only be modified by staff.

As far as I understand, changing this would be a very fast job. Low-impact, yes, but it would fix an **inaccuracy in the site's description of a mod tool** and would hopefully be very easy to fix.